# What is the difference between NA and missing and how to code them in R?

Tags: r, missing-data

I have a description of a dataset stating the following:

- Non applicable (NA) is coded as 88888
- Missing data is coded as blank or 99999

I thought NA is the equivalent to missing data, which would make the above-mentioned equivalent. Or does non applicable stand for impossible values (e.g., dividing by zero)? If they are treated as equivalent, I could simply convert 88888, 99999 and blanks to NA. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Dear downvoter. Downvoting etiquette suggests you leave a constructive comment with your downvote. Otherwise the OP has nothing but a downvote to learn from.

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing specifics of your dataset. If the description tells you the NA and missing are coded differently, there is likely a reason for it. It's probably not the best idea to just code them the same.

Comment: @ Mike H. I totally agree and that's why I am suspicious. However, this is the only information provided in the data set description. But how could I distinguish them? The true missing ones would miss randomly but the "not applicable" might miss not randomly.

Comment: You're asking a question about data cleaning without posting any data so it's hard to say. For example if the column is numeric vs character there might be different approaches. A reproducible example with some data and a specific question would be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Yes, NA is the equivalent to "empty cell"

You can do this to reduce the file size

```
data$column_with_8888s = ifelse(data$column_with_8888s == 8888, NA, data$column_with_8888s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing data is `NA` in R. You will have to set or calculate your own bases on questions when looking at summary data if you need a slightly different definition of missing in this context.

Sometimes it can be useful to get counts of these BEFORE converting them.

```
not_applicables <- lapply(mydata, function(x) sum(x == "88888") 
missings <- lapply(mydata, function(x) sum(x == "999999"))

mydata <- as.data.frame(lapply(mydata, function(x) {
     x[x %in% c('88888','99999') <- NA
     x 
}
```

Not applicable, is likely a category that you may not wish to exclude, because if you convert to factor, summary will not distinguish between them.

Alternatively, you may be able to fix this right when you load your data:

```
read.csv(..., na.strings = c("88888","99999"))
```